# Why was Father that old, compared to Kellogg?

Tags: fallout-4

Father was old and sick. Kellogg was way older than him, but he still looks young and fresh when you get to see him. One could argue that this was because of the parts he had implemented. Why did they let father age in the institute. Ok, gray hair doesn't mean that one is old, but he clearly looked more than a 60 year old than Kellogg, who has to be somewhere around 100 minimum.

Is this explained somewhere or is this some kind of "hole" in the story?

Answer (score 6):

Kellogg's cybernetic enhancements halted his aging, and extended his lifespan in addition to whatever else they were for. You can read about Kellogg and his enhancements on Father's terminal.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder, why Father did not use those himself, although he just had an incureable sickness.

Comment: I think Kellogg's enhancements were experimental and one of the effects was that the Institute gained complete control over him.  Also, to me it seemed Kellogg was mentally unstable at the end because of the implants.  Father probably wasn't comfortable with either of these side effects

Comment: @TrudleR For much the same reason that although Synths are pretty much superior to humanity in every way, the Institute still treat them as worse than a toaster. The Institute are human purists, as much as the Bortherhood, and they themselves would never become any less than fully human.